# Force minted to insert new space in code that won't fit on the page

Tags: listings, line-breaking, highlighting, minted, code

Essentially I would like to have `listings`' `breaklines` option on `minted`. I can't seem to find it. I could manually insert new lines but it becomes difficult when the code comes from an external file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I'll just have to stick to modifying inline text (or using `listings` if necessary)

Comment: One question : I'm working on a Python tool to highlight listings. What are the fetaures that you think to be important for highlighting ?

Comment: Well the basic is line-numbering, syntax highlighting, the ability to have code in the file and load it from an external file, the ability to have code inline (like $ $ or \verb+ +), and if possible the ability to refactor the code (that is understand it in the first place, usually) to add linebreaks and such to make sure it fits on the output.

Good luck.

Comment: BTW if you put your comment about `minted` not supporting linebreak as a response, I can upvote it and pick it as the best answer.

Comment: @projectmbc: would you be interested in adding ConTeXt support as well. I am the author of t-vim module for context, and would like to support other tools as well. All that is needed is that the tool generate TeX code in a certain form. The t-vim module already takes care of all the book-keeping. If you are interested we can discuss details on chat or offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment, minted dose not supported lines breaking : [see this discusion](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=21).